# Bringing children to the front of the stage depending on y-axis value

Tags: actionscript, stage

I just have a simple problem that needs resolving and I am pretty new to actionscript, I am making a sideScroller game where enemy troops spawn in randomly on some y value and then go across the screen, but how do I make it to where if they are lower on the y-axis(higher up on the screen), they appear in front of the others? They are troops so it looks bad if their legs overlap other people below them when it is supposed to look as if they are behind them. I hope I am explaining this well. 
Any help would be awesome!
thanks

Answer (score 0):

Keep all your troops in an Vector. First, sort them based on the y value. Then, iterate through the vector, and if the depth of the element at i is lower than the element at i+1, you should swap the objects' depths. Hope this helps, if you need more details, let me know.